# How do I prove a basic and obvious-looking set relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm a beginner in set theory, but the exercises asking for proof for intuitively obvious set relations like $A\cap A=A$. I don't know where to start. It will be appreciated if there is an example.

p.s. Mathematics consists of proving the most obvious thing in the least obvious way. - Polya

**Add.** I don't know the reason but I can't use comment. @amWhy.

No proof for $\left(x \in A \;\wedge \; x \in A\right)\ \leftrightarrow \left( x \in A\right)$ ?

Comment: It think it highly depends on how you define those operations (in this example, $\cap$). Although, I guess the definition is $C=A\cap B\Leftrightarrow C=\{x\,|\,x\in A\;\land\;x\in B\}$, so you might want to try starting from there.

Comment: You need to have at least 15 rep to comment.

Answer (score 2):

$$A\cap A = \{x\mid x \in A \;\text{and}\; x \in A\} = \{x \mid x \in A\} = A$$

That reads as follows: $A\cap A$ is the set of all elements that are in both $A$ and $A$, which is simply the set of all elements in $A$, which is exactly $A$.

Comment: In ten minutes you retagged five different questions. Maybe slow down a little bit?

Comment: Point taken, @Asaf. When I get in an "editing mode" (like with most tasks I undertake), I get in a "zone" and can get carried away. I'll try to be more careful.

Answer (score 1):

One of the standard ways to go about this type of equalities consists in proving, in this case, that
$A \cap A \subset A$ and $A \cap A \supset A$ i.e. proving that every element of $A \cap A$ also belongs to $A$ and viceversa.

Comment: Which is exactly the answer already given below.

Comment: I didn't write it after reading yours, sorry.

Comment: No big worry. It happens.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps begin by taking an element $a\in A \cap A$. Then since $a$ lies in both $A$ and $A$, then it must lie in $A$. So we have $A \cap A \subseteq A$. The other way is a similar argument.

A great strategy of showing two sets are equal is to take an arbitrary element of one set and showing that it must lie in the other set. Then do this for the other direction.

Comment: Doesn't this just reduce proving $A=A \cap A$ to proving $a \land a \Leftrightarrow a$? How would you go about proving the latter?

Comment: I think that we would just call the latter "simplification of a logical expression." The OP's question is a bit trivial in that regard.

Comment: Wouldn't we have to prove it from some axioms of propositional logic?

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like obvious advice, but if you are stuck, always go back to the definition.  I find this helps when trying to prove things that might seem clear.  In general it helps when you dont know where to begin.